# Beautifulsoup: Get a range of divs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just found out about how to process webpages in python using BeautifulSoup.
There's a list of `div` from which I want to get those in a specific range. The range is defined by two `div` that have a `h2` child.
How would I do that? Thank you for your support!

EDIT: I added an actual representation of my html code below instead of a previous "simplified" version that was missing tags.
The new code shows a root `div` with class `foo-bar-details`.
Nested are 9 `div` tags. Two of which have a nested `h2` tag. All of those 9 `div` tags contain `img` elements deeply nested within. What I need is each `img` element of those `div`s that are **between** the ones containing the `h2` element.
An expected outcome if applied to the html code below would be:

```
<img src="../../images/123456_thumb.jpg" alt="Image 123456" title="Image 123456">
<img src="../../images/67890_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 67890 " title="Image 67890">
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="foo-bar-details">
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-sand-bg" id="sec-feat-3-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 info-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>fsuhfsdf </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Feat</strong><a href="../linkglossary0.pdf" class="link" title="test"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-39826.html"><img src="../../images/39826_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 39826" title="Image 39826 "></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-sand-bg" id="sec-feat-3-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 info-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>JHFDFD </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Feat</strong><a href="../linkglossary2.pdf" class="link" title="test"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-223234.html"><img src="../../images/223234_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 223234" title="Image 223234 "></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-sand-bg" id="sec-feat-3-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 info-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>sdfsdf </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Feat</strong><a href="../linkglossary1.pdf" class="link" title="test"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-223823.html"><img src="../../images/223823_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 223823" title="Image 223823 "></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element-header mystic-bg padding-y-10 padding-x-20" id="elem-4">
        <h2 class="h3 margin-bottom-5">
            Foo 
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-inline margin-0">
            <li> <a href="#foo-feat-4-1">Foo feature</a> </li>
            ... 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="info-panel-header" class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-se-6 element-info">
                <div class="col-se-12">
                    <div class="row">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-123456.html"><img src="../../images/123456_thumb.jpg" alt="Image 123456" title="Image 123456"></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-wild-sand-bg" id="sec-feat-4-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 info-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Foo strin: </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Barbar</strong><a href="../test.pdf" class="link" title="test"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Mine: </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            TEST<a href="../link.pdf" class="my-link" title="title"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-67890.html"><img src="../../images/67890_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 67890 " title="Image 67890"></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element-header mystic-bg padding-y-10 padding-x-20" id="elem-5">
        <h2 class="h3 margin-bottom-5">
            Bar 
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-inline margin-0">
            <li> <a href="#foo-feat-5-1">Bar feature</a> </li>
            ... 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-sand-bg" id="sec-feat-3-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 info-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>fsuhfsdf </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Feat</strong><a href="../linkglossary0.pdf" class="link" title="test"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-39826.html"><img src="../../images/39826_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 39826" title="Image 39826 "></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-sand-bg" id="sec-feat-3-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 info-panel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>fsuhfsdf </strong> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 margin-bottom-10">
                        <p class="margin-0">
                            <strong>Feat</strong><a href="../linkglossary0.pdf" class="link" title="test"><span class="icon-help"></span></a> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 foo-images">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="image-209876.html"><img src="../../images/209876_thumb.JPG" alt="Image 209876" title="Image 209876 "></a> 
                    <div class="img-description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you require specifically `beautifulsoup` or are you open for other modules (`lxml`)?

Comment: Open to anything!

Comment: To be clear, you want all `div`s between the first and last one that contains an `h2` or do you want only the `div`s the contain an `h2`?

Comment: Post your expected output as well.Your statement is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution involving `lxml.html`:

We extract all `div`s between the *first* and *last* `div`s which contain an `h2` tag:

```py
import lxml.html


# HTML file saved as "file.html"
file_name = "file.html"
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(f.read())

# all_div = tree.findall('div')
all_div = tree.find_class('foo-bar-details')[0].findall('div')
start, stop = None, None
for k, div in enumerate(all_div):
    if div.findall('h2') and start is None:
        print("Range starts at %d" % k)
        start = k
        continue
    if div.findall('h2') and start is not None:
        print("Range stops at %d" % k)
        stop = k + 1  # add one as range stops at k - 1
        continue

# div_list = all_div[start:stop]
img_list = [_.xpath('.//img') for _ in all_div[start:stop]]
print(img_list)
# [[], [<Element img at 0x20b58d73f40>], [<Element img at 0x20b58d73f90>], []]

# Or
img_list = [_.xpath('.//img/@src') for _ in all_div[start:stop]]
print(img_list)
# [[], ['../../images/123456_thumb.jpg'], ['../../images/67890_thumb.JPG'], []]
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: The result is not nested right? Its just a list? Because what I'm trying to do next is get all img tags from those div tags. If I iterate over div_list I receive a lot of doublets.

Comment: @tzippy It depends on what you mean by accurate: Only the outer `div`s will be considered (see the edit). So if this is the expected result it'll be accurate, else you might want to consider a recursion.

Comment: I realised my simplified sample doesn't make sense, it was too simplified. I added a more detailed explanation of what I actually want to get from the html page.

Comment: @tzippy I've slightly edited two lines in the code - that should do it

Comment: ! Thanks, this works! I had to add `if stop is None: stop = start + 2` for the case that there is no last `h2` element

Answer (score 0):

Another solution involving SimplifiedDoc:

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html ='''
<div class="foo-bar-details">
    <div class="element-header mystic-bg padding-y-10 padding-x-20" id="elem-4">
        <h2 class="h3 margin-bottom-5">
            Foo 
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-inline margin-0">
            <li> <a href="#foo-feat-4-1">Foo feature</a> </li>
            ... 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="info-panel-header" class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40">Test 1</div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-wild-sand-bg" id="foo-feat-4-1">Test 2</div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 " id="foo-feat-4-2">Test 3</div>
    <div class="padding-y-10 padding-x-40 gray-wild-sand-bg" id="foo-feat-4-3">Test 4</div>
    <div class="element-header mystic-bg padding-y-10 padding-x-20" id="elem-5">
        <h2 class="h3 margin-bottom-5">
            Bar 
        </h2>
        <ul class="list-inline margin-0">
            <li> <a href="#foo-feat-5-1">Bar feature</a> </li>
            ... 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
divs = doc.select('div.foo-bar-details').divs.contains('<h2')
print ([div.id for div in divs])
divs = doc.select('div.foo-bar-details').divs.notContains('<h2')
print ([div.id for div in divs])
```

Result:

```
['elem-4', 'elem-5']
['info-panel-header', 'foo-feat-4-1', 'foo-feat-4-2', 'foo-feat-4-3']
```

Simplifieddoc library does not rely on the third-party library, which is lighter and faster, perfect for beginners.
Here are more examples [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find `<img>` tags and corresponding `<h2>` to which the images belong to.

This example (`txt` variable contains the HTML snippet from your question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = {}
for img in soup.select('div:has(h2) ~ div img'):
    out.setdefault(img.find_previous('h2').get_text(strip=True), []).append(img['src'])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Bar': ['../../images/39826_thumb.JPG', '../../images/209876_thumb.JPG'],
 'Foo': ['../../images/123456_thumb.jpg', '../../images/67890_thumb.JPG']}
```